# Reveal.js markdown fragment

Tags: javascript, markdown, reveal.js, presentation

I creating a presentation with `Reveal.js` and I'm using `markdown` to write it.

Consider a section like

```
<section data-markdown>
    <script type="text/template">
        ## Title

        > A little quote with some `code`
    </script>
</section>
```

I would like the `> Quote` to become a fragment and appear at mouse clink.
If I simply use `<!-- .element: class="fragment" -->` as it is stated in the `reveal.js` documentation, only the `code` part becomes a fragment.

How can I make all of the `> A little quote with some code` paragraph become a fragment?

Comment: I have the same issue: in my case, the software *thinks* the fragment is the italic word in a bullet point list. I guess he gives the "fragment" status to the nested formatted element.

Comment: Is it possible this was a bug and it was fixed? When I try it with `<!-- .element: class="fragment" -->` I don't get the behavior you're speaking of. However, I'm using a revealjs markdown plugin in VSCode and there is a quirky behavior that is related to this question, so I will post an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a VSCode-reveal (an extension for VSCode) that lets me do markdown files and generates the Reveal wrapping. There is a shortcut syntax for fragments `{.fragment}`.

It's quirky when markdown formatting is applied, as it tends to "stick" to the closest element. For example, I can get the problem you describe if I do this:

```
## Title

> A little quote with some `code`{.fragment}
```

But if I leave a space after the `'code'` part, it gives the desired behavior, probably because it applies to the quote's element, rather than the code formatted element:

```
## Title

> A little quote with some `code` {.fragment}
```

However, using `<!-- .element: class="fragment" -->` I could not reproduce your problem. I suspect this is a difference in reveal versions.